# In SystemVerilog, can events be defined in ports

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In Verilog, I know we can't pass "events" between modules. Howe about in System Verilog ? I would like the event "trig" hooking the trigger source blocks "eventGen" and is consumed by the block "eventConsume" Some how I get compilation error

Code:

```
module propagateEvents;

reg clk;
event trig;

initial
begin
    clk = 1'b0;
end

always #10 clk = ~clk;

eventGen eventGen (trig, clk);
eventConsume eventConsume (trig, clk);

endmodule

module eventGen(trigGen, clk);

input clk;
event trigGen;

reg count[3:0];

initial
    count = 0;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    count = count + 1'b1;
    if (count == 'h8)
        ->trigGen;
end

endmodule

module eventConsume(trigConsume, clk);

input clk;
event trigConsume;

always @(trigConsume)
begin
    $display("Trigger caught");
end
endmodule
```

Comment: I get the error as "Error-[RILIP] Register in low conn of input port
propagateEvents.sv, 21
"trigGen"
  Non-net variable 'trigGen' cannot be an input or inout port.


Error-[RILIP] Register in low conn of input port
propagateEvents.sv, 40
"trigConsume"
  Non-net variable 'trigConsume' cannot be an input or inout port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a port direction; ex. `inout event`. Working example [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/U3n). SystemVerilog can also use `ref event`.

Note that `event` is not synthesizable. Also `reg count[3:0]` needs to be `reg [3:0] count`.

```
module eventGen(output event trigGen, input clk);
reg [3:0] count;
initial count = 0;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    count = count + 1'b1;
    if (count == 'h8)
        ->trigGen;
end
endmodule

module eventConsume(input event trigConsume, input clk);
always @(trigConsume)
begin
    $display("Trigger caught");
end
endmodule
```

Comment: No need to use a `ref` port. An event variable used in an assignment to another event passes a handle to the event, which is in itself a reference. Just make the port an `output` to `eventGen` and an `input` to `eventConsume`

Comment: Can we assign event data type to other event data type. I have two or more events, say eventA, eventB, eventC. I would like the "trigConsume" to be eventA | eventB | eventC; in other words assign trgConsume = eventA | eventB | eventC is valid semantically ?

Comment: `always @(eventA or eventB or enventC) ->trigConsume;` or `always @(eventA) ->trigConsume; always @(eventB) ->trigConsume; always @(eventC) ->trigConsume;`.  Doing `trigConsume=eventA`, will alias it to eventA, but `trigConsume=eventB`, will override the alias. `eventA=trigConsume; eventB=trigConsume;` will alias everything. See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) section 6.17 _Event data type_